# How to style MUI Table Pagination component

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to move Rows Per Page over to the left. How do I do that?

```
const defaultMaterialTheme = createTheme();
<ThemeProvider theme={defaultMaterialTheme}>
        <TablePagination
          component="div"
          count={customers.length}
          page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
```

[image]

Trying overriding the theme but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) CSS property to reorder the [TablePagination items](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-pagination/#css):

```
<TablePagination
  sx={{
    "& .MuiTablePagination-spacer": {
      order: 2
    },
    "& .MuiTablePagination-selectLabel": {
      order: 0
    },
    "& .MuiTablePagination-select": {
      order: 1
    },
    "& .MuiTablePagination-displayedRows": {
      order: 3
    },
    "& .MuiTablePagination-actions": {
      order: 4
    }
  }}
...
```

[image: Edit frosty-gould-94omlz]